# Handle concurrency on token creation in nodejs

Tags: node.js, concurrency, axios, es6-promise

I have one endpoint that is used to create a new access token in case the previous one was expired.
The flow is the following:

- an endpoint is called
- the statusCode returned is 401, this means that the access token is not valid anymore
- I call the famous endpoint that provide a fresh access token.

My question is: if two endpoints receive 401 as statusCode, how can I make sure that the creation of the access token is called only once?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) if axios response promise is rejected on 4XX http status codes. Then it could be something like this.

```js
async function doRequests(token) {
    const firstReq = makeFirstReq(token)
    const secondReq = makeSecondReq(token)
    
    try {
        await Promise.all([firstReq, secondReq])
    } catch(error) {
        // You would have to wrap this in a try...catch too
        // also only do this if the status code is 4XX
        const newToken = await getFreshToken()
        await doRequests(newToken)
    }
}
```